# How to organize my data in country-year data, meaning one row for each country-year pair in dataset

Tags: r

I want to organize my data into country-year data, meaning every country-year pair has a row (Denmark 2020, Denmark 2019, Denmark 2018). I also want to have only one column for the CPI score, rank, etc.

[image: CPI 2020-2012]

Comment: You have a link with no description. Is that link to the data? Very few people will blindly click a link on a public Internet internet forum. For fastest help, please post your data within the question, not at a link. Try pasting the output of `dput(youre_data)`

Comment: OPs rarely get solution advice to their questions without first posting a solution attempt.  Suggest you review the powerful pivot functions of the tidyverse: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html  Read that over, experiment with your data then post an attempt.  Good advice should follow soon thereafter.

Comment: Hmm.  [Two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733313/how-to-create-a-country-year-data-using-mutate) requesting help pivoting CPI data involving data from Denmark in 2020 posted within 5 minutes of each other.  Perhaps there's scope for collaboration? :=)